# How is it not illegal and more importantly ethical for Additional Tier-1 bonds to be written off in case of rescue or liquidation of the company?

Tags: india, bonds, high-yield

Additional Tier-1 (AT-1) bonds issued in India, as I understand is regulated by RBI, the central bank in the country. It seems if the company faces severe losses,the RBI can then activate a Point of Non-Viability Trigger (PONV) and  write down the AT-1 bonds. How is it legal and ethical to do so?

Comment: A first guess is that you know (or should know) before you buy them that this might happen, and that's part of the risk you take.

Comment: This risk should be factored into the price you are willing to pay for such bonds.

Comment: Yes. I agree that you should be aware of the risk when you buy them. But does the greed for a bit more yield justify writing them off completely, in case of poor performance by the firm? They can be penalized with a slight or a significant cut. But just writing them off completely! Punishment should be proportional to the 'crime', don't you think?

Comment: By "writing down" the bonds, what do you mean? Are they converted to equity, perhaps? Or are you implying they're somehow made worthless / worth less?

Comment: Not converted to equity. As far as I understand, written off completely. They are quasi debt instruments, which do not have any fixed maturity period or a redemption date. They are callable at the initiative of the issuer after a minimum period of five years.

Comment: The essential element of this instrument is that they are hybrid capital securities that absorb losses in accordance with their contractual terms when the capital of the issuer falls below a certain level. That is, in case the Common Equity Tier-1 ratio falls below a threshold level, the holders of such bonds shall bear the losses without the issuer being liquidated. The terms and conditions include a provision, for them to be written off upon the occurrence of a trigger event.

Comment: What happens to the common equity when these bonds are written down?